# SSRS, exporting separate EXCEL sheet for each group by element

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on SSRS. I have a table having a group by column . And I used page break. so its exporting separate tab for each group element within same EXCEL. But I want to export separate EXCEL sheet for each group by element.

Answer (score 0):

I do this on a few reports and it worked for me.

Try this - [Method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx)